# Consistent size of an element in every device screen

Tags: html, css

**This is my code:**

```html
<div class="box cntr" style="width: 52.9134px; height: 52.9134px; background: #c04848; border-radius: 50%;">
    <h2 id="amount" style="text-align: center">3</h2>
  </div>
```

The width is 52.9134px but when you open it in other device the element will become smaller than the original size  in desktop screen. I want the element will be the same size in all devices like iphones, ipad, android phones and etc.

Comment: the width is the same in all devices but as the screen resolutions different from one to one you see different width. for instance 1px in hd resolution is very different to 1px in 4k resolution

Comment: what is your question? the width of the element will be 52px on all screens. 52px will look different on all screens as a result of differing resolution though

Comment: using `em` instead of `px` may solve the problem, if not then you have to write media query in css for different screen resolution

Comment: Stop tagging unrelated tags.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
.myClass{
    height: 15vw; /* or vh */
    width: 15vw; /* or vh */
}
```

to remain a fixed aspect ratio between screen and element.

But you will have some trouble with portrait and landscape mode. You would need to write a media query or do something with js to account for that.

You could also use `em` or `rem`. `rem` would circumvent any changes you made to the font-size in a previous container.

Did you set your viewport in your HTML?

Do you have a width set on the html or body element?

Answer (score 0):

You can check by debugging that when it is seen in other devices does it gets overridden.
If that's the case you can add `!important` after your style like this

```
width: 52.9134px !important;
```

Same for every other styles too.

Or if they are not overridden and you don't want to use `!important` (because some will say that's not proper according to standards) then use can use `max` and `min` according to your need.
If they are seen smaller then `min-width: 52.9134px` or if they are seen bigger then `max-width: 52.9134px`. Same for other styles too.

But remember one thing that you have to use `!important` if `max` `min` gets overridden too.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent 'smart' resizing from phones and tablets, you should add the meta viewport tag to the `head` of the document:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

This tag instructs the browser to NOT zoom out. It instructs the browser to stick to the device width and to NOT scale.